# redirecting to a common page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee

i want to redirect all request to common page and on that common page i want to check whether this url exists or not.

for example my base URL is www.iCare.com

when any one want to access his clinic page eg(www.icare.com/myclinic) the url is redircted to a common page and at that page i get the current url and matches it with DB that this URL exists or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Filter`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html) (not the common page) is what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

Servlet filter is a better option. With servlet filter you need not redirect.